# Delete Duplicates with LINQ in VB. NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, duplicates

I'm using a List(of String) which contains the following:

```
1
2
3
1
4
2
5
3
1
```

I am trying to remove the duplicates with `LINQ`. But til now I cant see any chance to manage it :(

I tried:

```
StringList = StringList.Distinct()
```

but this causes an fatal error.

Comment: "*this causes an fatal error*", please show the exact error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is that you're trying to assign the result of `Distinct()` (which is an `IEnumerable(Of String)`) to an variable of type `List(Of String)`.

Try this:

```
Dim StringList As List(Of String) = ...
StringList = StringList.Distinct().ToList()
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer so that the rest of us can see that you have found a solution.

Comment: @user2597665 also you should show your appreciation to the person giving you some help. You haven't awarded a single answer yet, even though you have got solutions for all your questions: do you think that this is the right behaviour?

Comment: and how can i award it varocarbas? there is no more button to do so.. :(

Comment: @user2597665 You cannot accept a comment, only an answer. Accept an answer by clicking the green check next to it. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: lol.. finally i found it... as u said before: i should sleep xD